# ServiceStack OrmLite OrderBy on joined table columns

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I wish to make an OrderBy statement in OrmLite, using data from multiple joined tables in my query:

```
myQuery.OrderBy<MainTable, SubTable>((m, s) => m.Col1 < s.Col2)
```

just as you can with OrmLite's WHERE clauses:

```
myQuery.Where<MainTable, SubTable>((m, s) => m.Col1 < s.Col2)
```

But it is not possible with OrderBy. Can I work around this issue in an alternative way?

Answer (score 3):

Use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` to order by multiple columns, e.g:

```
q.OrderBy<MainTable>(m => m.Col1)
 .ThenBy<SubTable>(s => s.Col2);
```

If you need to OrderBy an expression you can use a string:

```
q.OrderBy("Col1 < Col2");
```

For [typed properties in string expressions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-columnt-and-tablet-apis) use:

```
q.OrderBy($"{q.Column<MainTable>(m => m.Col1)} < {q.Column<SubTable>(s => s.Col2)}");
```

In the latest v5.5.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget) you will also be able to use a typed expression from multiple tables in your OrderBy, e.g:

```
q.OrderBy<MainTable, SubTable>((m, s) => m.Col1 < s.Col2 ? m.Col1 : s.Col2)
```

Comment: This works for some expressions, but would it be possible to include linq in an expression like: `q.OrderBy<MainTable, SubTable>((m, s) => (m.Col1 != null ? s.Col2 : s.Col3))` - and leverage OrmLite's to translate to proper target SQL instead of doing string expressions?

Comment: @PerErikGransøe This has been added to OrmLite, please see my updated answer.